# Imprimir "Hello World" en Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Quiero mostrar "Hello World" en Android Studio sin tener que utilizar un AVD o mi celular. Quisiera saber si Android Studio tiene algún tipo de interactive shell, como en Python, donde pueda ver el output de mi código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio es para programar aplicaciones Android con Java o Kotlin por lo que necesitas AVD o un telefono con android para probar tus aplicaciones.

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar codigo e imprimir la salida en una consola, usa IntelliJ o algun otro IDE compatible con Kotlin